# Ruby object design for series of methods

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm trying to parse a string from a mess ("SOME.String_With-bits.txt") into a clean string ("Some String With Bits") in Ruby.  I'd like to be able to call a nice simple method and get the cleaned string - Eg. `clean_string = NameParser::parse(messy_string)`

I'm trying to do a nice testable design here, but I'm really struggling to come up with a structure (the actual parsing code is no problem).  Parsing the string is quite complex and I'd like to separate out the stages.  I've tried this:

```
class NameParser
  def self.parse(name)
    name = self.correct_case(name)
    name = self.correct_whitespace(name)
    name = self.remove_extension(name)
    return name
  end


  def self.correct_case(name) ....
  def self.correct_whitespace(name) ....
  def self.remove_extension(name) ....
end
```

It looks HORRIFIC.  What can I do?  Can anyone point me to a similar implementation somewhere on Github?

Comment: You should define exactly what the characters you want to remove are. Plus, you have a remove extension but in your example, the extension remains. Is it a mistake ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough - I'm good with the code to do the actual parsing, I'm just looking for a nice clean design/structure for how to implement it in an OOP way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid programming so much classbased, and instead program more object based, You can remove all the self. methods, and make a convenience method self.parse if you like:

```
def self.parse string
  new.parse(string) 
end
```

Or create a parser with the string in the initialize. It depends a bit on how you use it exactly which feels best.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code could do that:

```
class Object
  def chain_methods(start_value, *methods)
    methods.inject(start_value) { |last, method| self.send(method, last) }
  end
end
```

And the usage:

```
NameParser.chain_methods(name, :correct_case, :correct_whitespace, :remove_extension)
```